# Maximum Likelihood

Tags: probability, parameter-estimation

Find the maximum likelihood estimator of $f(x|\theta) = \frac{1}{2}e^{(-|x-\theta|\:)}$,

$-\infty < x < \infty$ ; $-\infty < \theta < \infty$.

I am confused of how to deal with the absolute value here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likelihood function $$L(x;\theta)=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{2}e^{-|x_i-\theta|}=\frac{1}{2^n}e^{-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|x_i-\theta|}$$

$$\ln L(x;\theta)=-n\ln2-\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i-\theta|$$

$$\frac{\partial\ln L(x;\theta)}{\partial\theta}=\sum_{i=1}^n \text{sign } (x_i-\theta)$$ because $|x|'=\text{sign }x,x\ne0$

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I have one more question, how should I express the $\theta$ estimator formally?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f(x|\theta)\:$denotes the $\text{pdf}\:$such that$\:x\:$takes on any value belonging to the set  of real numbers with$\:\theta\:$viewed as a fixed probability.

The likelihood function$\:L(\theta|x)\:$is such that$\:x\:$represents an observed sample point, and$\:\theta\:$varying over all parameter values.

Where$\:X=\{X_1,...,X_n\}\:$and$\:X=x\:\:$the observed value

Therefore both functions aren't exactly the same and aren't written in the same fashion.

$\:L(\theta|x)=\large\prod_\limits{i=1}^n$$\frac{1}{2}e^{-|x_i-\theta|}=\frac{1}{2^n}e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i-\theta|}\:\:$and the MLE minimizes$\:\:\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}|x_i-\theta|=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}|x_{(i)}-\theta|$

with order statistics $\:x_{(1)},...,x_{(n)}$

For$\:\:\theta\in[x_{(j)},x_{(j+1)}],$

$\mathcal{S}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}|x_{(i)}-\theta|=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{j}(\theta-x_{(i)})+\sum\limits_{i=j+1}^{n}(x_{(i)}-\theta)=(2j-n)\theta-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{j}x_{(i)}+\sum\limits_{i=j+1}^{n}x_{(i)}$

$\mathcal{S}\:$is a linear function depending on$\:\theta\:$that increases for $2j-n>0,\:$and decreases for$\:2j-n<0$

If$\:n=2k+1; k\in\mathbb{N},\:$the likelihood is minimized at$\:\theta^{\star}=x_{(\frac{n+1}{2})},\:$wich is the median order value.

If$\:n=2k; k\in\mathbb{N},\:$the likelihood is minimized for $\:\theta^{\star}\in(x_{(\frac{n}{2})},x_{(\frac{n+1}{2})}),\:$because it is constant over this interval.